# How to start a background service in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have written a dependency service(interface resides in portable project and implementing class in android project).
In the Android project there's a class extending from `Service`.
I'm trying to call the `startService` from the class used in the dependency service using following code. But the code inside `startService` never gets executed.

```
public interface IService
{
    void RunService();
}
    
    
class xyz : IService
{
    public void Runservice()
    {
        Forms.context.startService(new Intent(Forms.Context,typeof(MyService)));
    }
}
    
class MyService : service
{
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent,StartCommandFlags flags,int startId)
    {
        Log.Debug("MyService","Service started...");
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
}
```

Inside `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
DependencyService.get<IService>().RunService();
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? If so, it shouldn't even compile. Your `OnStartCommand` is missing its parameters and the Xamarin API uses `PascalCase` for public members: there is no `startService` method, it's `StartService`.

Comment: No its not actual code. Actual code is correct, it compiles and runs also.

Comment: Only thing is service is not getting called.

Comment: Please post your actual code then.

Comment: @Dai I've updated the code